# Thumbnails of Excel files in Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph to generate Thumbnails for Excel spreadsheets, but it doesn't seem to be generating any thumbnail.

I have the following code:

```
var res = await GraphClient
    .QueryGraphAsync($"/drives/{drive.id}/items/{itemId}/thumbnails", user);

var resp = await res.Content
    .ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The `QueryGraphAsync` method looks like this:

```
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta" + relativeUrl);

var accessToken =
    await GetAccessTokenAsync(user);

req.Headers.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

return await Client.SendAsync(req);
```

The return that is coming back is just an empty array. it is not erroring, just not returning anything.  If change the URL try and request a specific thumbnail like `/4/large` at the end of URL, I get a message that says thumbnail doesn't exist.  This makes sense that there is currently no thumbnail for this.

What I'm looking for is a way to have the graph generate these thumbnails for me.  Can anybody help me understand what I'm missing?

I have uploaded a Word document and an Excel document.  The Word document is giving me thumbnail results, but the Excel document is not.

Comment: We have the same issue, this seems to be a bug in Excel Online somewhere. We've made a ticket here before this GitHub repo was locked down on bugs:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2849